# Problem with spring-database xml config after upgrading to Hibernate 5 and Spring 5

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I upgraded my application from Java7 to Java8, Spring 3.4 to Spring 5.1.4, Hibernate 4.2.11 to 5.2.11.

I checked the jars and I have updated spring jars (v5.1.4) and hibernate jars (5.2.11).

Resolved POM

```
<properties>
    <spring.security.version>5.1.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.25</slf4j.version>
    <dbcp.version>1.4</dbcp.version>
    <java-version>1.8</java-version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <displaytag.version>1.2</displaytag.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.2.11.Final</hibernate.version>
    <logback.version>1.1.2</logback.version>
    <jspapi.version>2.1</jspapi.version>
    <servletapi.version>2.5</servletapi.version>
    <jackson.version>1.9.10</jackson.version>
    <mysql.connector.version>8.0.13</mysql.connector.version>
    <spring.version>5.1.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
```

spring-database.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">                          

<context:component-scan base-package="com.s382.kris.*" />
<tx:annotation-driven />

<!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/s382?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull" />
    <property name="username" value="admin" />
    <property name="password" value="admin" />
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate 5 XML SessionFactory Bean definition-->
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />        
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>orm/User.hbm.xml</value>
    <value>orm/UserRole.hbm.xml</value>

        </list>
    </property>
<property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>             

<!-- MUST have transaction manager, using aop and aspects  -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
<tx:attributes>
    <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />
    <tx:method name="find*" read-only="true" />
    <tx:method name="*" />
</tx:attributes>
</tx:advice> 

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="allServices" expression="execution(* com.s382.kris.service.*.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="allServices" />
</aop:config>
```

'''

Stack Trace

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'companyController' defined in file [/home/barkha/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.7.RELEASE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/s382/WEB-INF/classes/com/s382/kris/controller/CompanyController.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0' while setting bean property 'transactionAttributeSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.methodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource#0' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#348f470f' of type [org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource] while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#348f470f': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3de1ec44' of type [org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.ExpressionBasedAnnotationAttributeFactory] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3de1ec44': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.config.method.GlobalMethodSecurityBeanDefinitionParser$DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandlerBeanFactory#0$created#0' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.method.GlobalMethodSecurityBeanDefinitionParser$DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandlerBeanFactory#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: ; nError creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Lookup method resolution failedested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean] from ClassLoader [ParallelWebappClassLoader
```

Application builds successfully but throws error on launching on tomcat9

Comment: It's been 2 years, did you ever find a solution that you could post as an answer?

Comment: I am sure I was able to fix this but I can hardly recall the details. Looking at this now I think the issue was with pom file. You may want to check your dependency hierarchy. You may have some dependencies included twice with different versions on your path, you will have to exclude the lower version. Also check the jars, if there are multiple jars for same dependency different versions.